# oracle global temporary commit

Tags: oracle, commit, temp-tables

I create a temporary table "create global temporary table abc (fields ..). I import the .csv file using Importer text.

```
create global temporary table abc (fields ..)
```

I look at the import script that completes the "commit".

```
insert into table (fields) values('s', 'c', 4, 7, .....);
insert into table (fields) values('a', 'fc', 2, 6, .....);
insert into table (fields) values('q', 'x', 45, 23, .....);

commit;
```

When you confirm the transaction data is deleted. However, if you insert without commit, the data is added, but the data is only visible in the sql window when insert.

Why does the transaction confirmation clear the data?

Comment: `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` vs `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` - https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-A48CB362-FC15-4A26-8386-906A55F6788E

Comment: "without commit, the data is added, but only visible in the add window" - I may be misinterpreting that, particularly what you mean by "add window" - but in a GTT the data in only ever visible to session that created it, whichever `on commit` option you use. If you need one session to insert and another to use the data - and can't combine them - then a GTT isn't suitable.

Comment: thank. then the default is ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS

Comment: As the name suggests, it's a table for **temporary** data.